# Is Circle of Willis unique to humans?

Tags: brain, neuroanatomy

I understand that Circle of Willis is a circulatory anastomotic system that provided blood to the brain.  I want to understand if this system is unique to humans or does it exist in other species or mammals to be more specific?

Comment: This is very trivial - it's a one word answer, no. I got my answer by go ogling "circle of willis dogs" hence closing as poorly researched.

Comment: I agree that the question could have been rephrased in a better way. Also, 90% questions here can be googled. It's more about getting pointed in the right direction - to publications and established research.

Comment: See the help pages on writing good quality questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two references that talk about the circle of Willis in different kind of mammals so i think it's right to say that this particular anastomotic system of arteries is not exclusive to humans.

Here are the two references:

http://www.neuroanatomy.org/2008/054_065.pdf

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14651482